# Problem with solving a conditional-probability question

Tags: probability

I have a problem with a statistics question.

The question is as follows:

I want to go to location B, but I am lost. To find this location I will ask random people where it is. There are two kind of people. 1/3 of the people will always lie where the location is, and 2/3 of the people have the probability ¾ that they are telling the truth, also they have a really bad memory, the moment that they told you the answer they will forget what they have said, so the answers will be independent.

I’ve drawn a tree diagram to show probabilities:
T=true
F=false
[image]

I need to answer the following questions:

1. You ask a random stranger where location b is. He says: "South". What is the chance this is the correct answer?
2. You ask for the second time to the same random stranger the same question. He gives the same answer. Show that the chance that this answer is correct equals to 1/2.
3. You ask the same question for the 3rd time to the same strangers. He gives the same answers. What is the chance that “South” is correct?
4. The 4th time you will ask the same random stranger if location B is in the North or South. He gives the same answer. Show that the chance that this answer is correct equals to 27/70
5. Lets say he didn't said the 4th time "South", but he said "North". Show that the chance that this answer is correct equals to 9/10

I got the following answers:

1): $$ {2\over3}*{3\over4}={1\over2} $$
2) $$ {({2\over3}*{3\over4} + {2\over3}*{3\over4})\over2}={1\over2} $$
3) $$ {({2\over3}*{3\over4} + {2\over3}*{3\over4} + {2\over3}*{3\over4})\over3}={1\over2} $$
4) I do not know

5) I do not know

I hope that someone can tell me the solution of the questions.

Comment: The standard approach to conditional probability questions as these is to use Bayes Theorem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem. May I ask where exactly you have found this question?

Comment: Since both this one and the one i flagged suspiciously ask for n = 4, i'll just assume i made a person's homework yesterday. Two persons, in fact

Comment: Thank you for the comments. Sorry for the duplicate posts. This was indeed a homework question, but the reason I asked it was beause I had not idea how to solve it and I have no idea where to ask it. These questions will not discussed in class, so in the end I still have no idea if I'm doing something correct if I'm not asking it here. So thank you for the help! The questions are given by mine teacher, so I do not have a reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for 5), the only possible events are now:

1. Forgetful guy answers 3 times right, then 1 wrong.
2. Forgetful guy answers 3 times wrong, then 1 right.
   With $$ 
   P(1.) = \frac{3*3*3*1}{4*4*4*4} = \frac{27}{256},
   P(2.) = \frac{1*1*1*3}{4*4*4*4} = \frac3{256} $$

So you calculate the probability of 1. happening out of both possible outcomes as: 
$$ 
\frac{P(1.)}{P(1.)+P(2.)} = 
\frac{\frac{27}{256}}{\frac{27}{256}+\frac3{256}} = 
\frac{27}{30} = 
\frac9{10}
$$